# import talib --- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'

Tags: python, import, ta-lib

I have an issue with TA-Lib import
I have created a venv for my python project and when I import talib and run my script I get

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/renaatvandewiele/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/renaatvandewiele/Desktop/GIT/bitrade/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import talib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'
```

I'm on a M1 MacBook Pro I did the brew install ta-lib and in my venv I did pip3 install TA-Lib.

```sh
(bitrade) (base) renaatvandewiele@Renaats-MBP bitrade % pip3 list
Package               Version
--------------------- -----------
aiohttp               3.8.0
aiosignal             1.2.0
async-timeout         4.0.0
attrs                 21.2.0
backports.zoneinfo    0.2.1
certifi               2021.10.8
charset-normalizer    2.0.7
click                 8.0.3
dateparser            1.1.0
Flask                 2.0.2
frozenlist            1.2.0
idna                  3.3
itsdangerous          2.0.1
Jinja2                3.0.2
MarkupSafe            2.0.1
multidict             5.2.0
numpy                 1.21.3
pandas                1.3.4
pip                   21.3.1
python-binance        1.0.15
python-dateutil       2.8.2
pytz                  2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim 0.1.0.post0
regex                 2021.11.2
requests              2.26.0
setuptools            49.2.1
six                   1.16.0
TA-Lib                0.4.21
tqdm                  4.62.3
typing-extensions     3.10.0.2
tzdata                2021.5
tzlocal               4.1
ujson                 4.2.0
urllib3               1.26.7
websockets            9.1
Werkzeug              2.0.2
yarl                  1.7.2
```

anyone who can guide me to a solution please?

Comment: note : also I run my app in  vscode and I have set my interpreter to my venv

Comment: Problem solved . was working in bitrade venv but Conda base was still open.. so Conda deactivate fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Conda base was still open ... Conda deactivate ... no more errors